# Migrating from TFS 2010 to TFS2013 - Workspace management

Tags: tfs

We are in the process of migrating/upgrading our TFS2010 to TFS2013, new infrastructure.

We are following the step by step upgrade guide.

Regarding workspaces, do the developers need to remove all the local mapping to the old TFS instance before the upgrade? If Yes, we can ask them to remove.

However is there any way to find out whether the developers have removed all their local workspaces from TFSadmin point of view rather than asking the developers to say whether they have removed or not?

Best Regards

Comment: Are you changing Physical servers / server names or is this an inplace upgrade?

Comment: Yes, we are changing the servers

Answer (score 0):

> However is there any way to find out whether the developers have
>   removed all their local workspaces from TFSadmin point of view rather
>   than asking the developers to say whether they have removed or not?

Installing [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) will allow you to see what workspaces exist for a particular User / Machine, it will also allow you to delete workspaces and to remove file locks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required when doing an upgrade to have developers remove workspaces. After the upgrade Visual Studio will automatically match it all up correctly.

Note: Make sure that you only do this for production. If you are doing a trial migration you MUST change the server ID to prevent VS getting confused!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee349259(v=vs.110).aspx